# implementing hashCode() for compound integer keys

Tags: java

I have a class which has three integers to represent it: a serverID, a streamID and an messageID.

I have some `HashSet` that are small but I do lots of stuff like set intersection on, and others that have 10K+ elements in.

There are only a handful of values for serverID, but they are truly random numbers with a full 32-bits of randomness.  Often there is only one serverID for a whole hashtable; other times just a couple of serverIDs.

The streamID is a small number, typically 0 but may be 1 or 2 sometimes.

The messageID is sequentially increasing for each serverID/streamID pair.

I currently have:

```
(-messageID << 24) ^ messageID ^ serverID ^ streamID
```

I want to understand that I have a good hash function despite having a sequentially increasing messageID and not a lot of other bits to mix in.

What makes a good `hashCode` and how can I best mix these three numbers?

Comment: I typically use [`HashCodeBuilder`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/builder/HashCodeBuilder.html) and [EqualsBuilder](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/builder/EqualsBuilder.html) from Apache commons-lang. Both methods use the approach suggested by Joshua Bloch in *Effective Java*.

Comment: @DuncanJones wouldn't that incur quite a performance impact?  Even if the hashcode is cached and the reflection-approach not used, there's a making an object etc in there.

Comment: Not sure, I'm afraid - maybe test and see? I tend to opt for well tested options (e.g. Apache commons libraries) and only optimise if I see a performance issue I can't accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally always use strategy implemented in `java.lang.String`:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            h = 31*h + val[off++];
        }
```

So, in your case I'd use the following: `31 * (31 * messageID + serverID) + streamID`

Comment: That puts the messageID into the low bits for low numbers; does a small hash table use the high bits or low bits?

Comment: @Will, I have no idea. about how it is working internally. But you can take a look on `java.util.AbstractMap`. The most of the implementation is there.

Answer (score 1):

eclipse gives it self good hashcode generation

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + messageID;
    result = prime * result + serverID;
    result = prime * result + streamID;
    return result;
}
```